# How to federate AD identities of a private domain to public services?

Tags: dns, active-directory, office365, amazon-cognito, adfs

I am trying to connect AWS Cognito to my private AD users. I installed AD FS and AD FS Proxy, but now the question: as my domain is private (domain.local), I do not have publicly trusted SSL certificate. Therefore I can not connect Cognito to my Proxy to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I am not versed in AWS Cognito, I would say this is expected behavior. I believe the principles for federation between an internal Active Directory domain to AWS Cognito via ADFS would be the same as an internal Active Directory domain to the Azure cloud / Office 365 via ADFS.  And that is, only domains which are publicly routable can get a publicly trusted SSL certificate.  Private  domains (like domain.local) are only ever able to get their own internal CA to trust them - but no public trust CAs will ever trust that private domain.  There is no way around that aspect.  To federate to Azure you must prove ownership of a domain, then verify it with a public trust authority, then create a required DNS TXT record, before you can add the domain to Office 365.  Without these steps completed, you cannot federate to anything.  There is a slight workaround for private domains in this scenario, but it would involve obtaining a publicly routable DNS domain which goes against the notion of what your trying to do with a quick test.  Just in case your interested, the workaround to federate an internal namespace to federate to public services is to:

1. Add a routable domain UPN suffix in Active Directory Domains and Trusts
2. Configure particular (or all) users with that routable UserPrincipleName
3. Synch the users to Azure / Office 365
4. Federate to the other public services

This is explained at the 29:05 mark in a Microsoft Office 365 Partner video titled: Office 365: [Configuring DirSync and Single Sign On with ADFS - Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=98-kbJVyms4&feature=youtu.be)

Note:  To get a wider audience, I would remove the [proxy](/questions/tagged/proxy) tag and replace it with [office365](/questions/tagged/office365).

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for such a comprehensive answer. I would like to adjust (and compress) my question a little bit before diving into DNS and public certificates: let's say, I need to access my federation metadata (internal network) from my PC over Internet by simply resolving IP of ADFS Proxy. With self-signed cert (I will ignore/skip the warning in browser). How should I set up the ADFS Proxy then?

Comment: Hi France, Please take the [tour] and see [ask].  Reason why I say that is because it will help you learn this site better.  What you are now asking is a whole new question, and it should be created as a new question.  This Comments section is not for new questions, it's designed to focus in on specific parts of the existing question, rather than new questions.  In your new question, you could always insert a hyperlink back to this one if you want to string the two together, conceptually.   I'm afraid I do not know the answer to this new question anyway.

Comment: Ok, back to your original answer: if I already have a Federation Server with Service configured, and I want to add a routable domain UPN suffix, do I need to reinstall ADFS or I can just add the suffix and eventually Publish it in WAP?

Comment: If you want to add a routable domain UPN suffix, you do not need to reinstall ADFS.  Just add the suffix manually.  Adding UP suffixes for users has no relation to what you publish in the WAP.   Here's another link for you I found:  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-to-prepare-a-non-routable-domain-such-as-local-domain-for-directory-synchronization-e7968303-c234-46c4-b8b0-b5c93c6d57a7

Comment: But I thought this is the way to "Publish New Application" (PNA), since when you are setting PNA it asks for external URL which must be the same as internal one. I believed that if I add the UPN suffix of publicly existing domain, I can federate from it, therefore accomplishing PNA.

Comment: But publishing new applications would be a wholly different aspect to cloud management than managing the synchronization of on-premise users to the cloud.  Makes sense?  I'm not versed in AWS so I'm not able to answer in the particulars.

Comment: I am trying to make my Federation Metadata available from the internet. I prepared Federation Service that generates it, and I installed ADFS proxy on another publicly available machine that intended to proxy requests from out to in. According to the MS docs I need to set up WAP, which is not possible for "domain.local" domains. For that reason I want to set up publicly resolvable UPN suffix and set up WAP accordingly. Am I going to the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure.  I'll research it.  If I don't post back here soon, it means I haven't found the answer yet.